# Warning: exif_imagetype(IMG-635b877fbb2892.73329302.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, converters, webp

I'm making an image converter and I wanted to make a condition to check the file extension et change it to another one, ex: if it's jpg/png change it to webp

I keep having the warning on the line 85, 90 and 95

```
<?php
require "db.php";
$pdo = new \PDO(DSN, USER, PASS);

if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])) {

    $files = $_FILES['files'];
    $fileName = $_POST['name'];
    $fileTag = $_POST['tag'];
    $fileDescription = $_POST['description'];

    $uploaded = array();
    $failed = array();

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'webp');

    foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {

        $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
        $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
        $file_error = $files['error'][$position];

        $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {

            if ($file_error === 0) {

                if ($file_size <= 2097152) /* 2mb */ {

                    $file_name_new = uniqid('IMG-', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                    $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $file_name_new;

                    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {

                        $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;

                        $query = "INSERT INTO images(name, tag, description, images) VALUES (:name, :tag, :description,:images)";
                        $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

                        $statement->bindValue(':name', $fileName, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $statement->bindValue(':tag', $fileTag, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $statement->bindValue(':description', $fileDescription, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $statement->bindValue(':images', $file_name_new, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $statement->execute();

                        $upload = $statement->fetchAll();
                    } else {
                        $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] failed to upload.";
                    }
                } else {
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] is too large.";
                }
            } else {
                $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] failed to upload {$file_error}.";
            }
        } else {
            $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] file extension '{$file_ext}' is not allowed.";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($uploaded)) {
        print_r($uploaded);
    }

    if (!empty($failed)) {
        print_r($failed);
    }
} else {
    echo 'no files';
}/* 
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_destination);
imagewebp($image, str_replace('jpg', 'webp', $file_name_new));

$image = imagecreatefrompng($file_destination);
imagewebp($image, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file_name_new));

$image = imagecreatefromwebp($file_destination);
imagepng($image, str_replace('webp', 'png', $file_name_new));

$image = imagecreatefromwebp($file_destination);
imagejpeg($image, str_replace('webp', 'jpg', $file_name_new));
 */
if (exif_imagetype($file_name_new) == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

    $image = imagecreatefrompng($file_destination);
    imagewebp($image, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file_name_new));

} elseif (exif_imagetype($file_name_new) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_destination);
    imagewebp($image, str_replace('jpg', 'webp', $file_name_new));

} elseif (exif_imagetype($file_name_new) == IMAGETYPE_WEBP) {

    $image = imagecreatefromwebp($file_destination);
    imagepng($image, str_replace('webp', 'png', $file_name_new));
    
}
```

It's not the best but i'll be working on making it better once the warning is gone

I tried to change the condition but kept having this warning
It also appeared when I made the converted file go to a folder

Comment: Look at your code - you're trying to access the file as if it's in the same folder as the PHP script. But you specifically saved it into the "uploads" folder, so you need to specify that path as well when you try to read it.

Comment: In other words, `if (exif_imagetype($file_destination)` is more likely to work, I would think